# What does the word "potential" mean in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, potential-energy

From Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd ed:

[image]

What should I be imagining when they say a "spherically symmetrical potential"? My main confusion is with the word potential, but let's also consider the 3 words together.

Comment: *"What should I be imagining when they say a "spherically symmetrical potential"?"* - an example of *a* spherically symmetric potential is a Coulomb like potential:  $V(r) \propto \frac{1}{r}$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$  Another example is an isotropic harmonic oscillator potential:  $V(r) \propto r^2$  Notice that in both cases, there is no *angular* dependence on the potential.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the equation modeling your wave function as

$$
\hat{H}\psi(\vec{r},t) = -i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\psi(\vec{r},t)
$$

with

$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m} + V(\vec{r},t)
$$

Potential means the term $V(\vec{r},t)$. And spherically symmectric means that

$$
V(\vec{r},t) = V(r, t)
$$

that is, only depends on the distance to the origin, not the direction

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that this potential has the shape of an infinitesimally thin shell?

Comment: No, what it means is that if you move on a particular spherical shell (centerd at the origin) you will no see any change in the potential

Answer (score 0):

1. The meaning is that in spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ your potential depends only on $r$ coordinate (for example $V(r)=\frac{const}{r}$ or even $V(r)=e^{-r}$ or $V(r)=a r^2$ or any arbitrary function of $r$ coordinate).
2. The solution itself may be a nice exercise in commutation relations, since it's enough to show that $[\vec{L},H]=0$